# iTunes Connect Beta Testing and Provisional certificates

Tags: ios, xcode6

i have to push new build to iTunes connect for internal testing . So that i took a archive from Xcode 6 by using default certificated generated by Xcode and then uploaded to iTunes connect which shows in pre-release tab after that I enabled TestFlight-beta testing for this build and added tester for internal testing.The tester doesn't receive any e-mail from Apple.

how can i invite user to do internal testing?

In my Dev center i already have specific provisional certificate for Ad-hoc,Development and Distribution.

please suggest me to do proper way.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224

I followed the tutorial or check iTunesConnect video posted on
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/TestFlight-v09-iTC-Export-sw.mov

Answer (score 0):

[image]I fixed the problem by regenerating distribution certification and choose the certification from Xcode 6 Make sure "beta-active-reports"=true on your selected certificate otherwise regenerate the certificate once again. after that i can received the "Invite" button on my iTunes connect. after getting invite please make sure you have configured your AppleId mail on iPhone using "Apple Mail" client only.